# regex replace only a part of the match

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace only a part of the string of a regex pattern match. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995358/1775888) but I don't get it...
How do I use substitution?

Example of what I want: keep the first slug digit, only replace others

`/09/small_image/09x/` > `/09/thumbnail/`
1st: `unknown digit`
2nd: `"small_image"`
3rd: `unknown digit + "x"`

Here is what I have so far:

```
var regexPattern = /\/\d\/small\_image\/\d*x/;
var regexPattern = /\/\d\/(small\_image\/\d*x)$1/;  ??

var result = regexPattern.test(str);
if (result) {
  str = str.replace(regexPattern, 'thumbnail');
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do, using complete sentences? I apologize if English isn't your first language

Comment: thanks for reply, sorry english isnt my first language. I want to know how to only replace part of string not replace whole regex pattern match string.

Comment: So the idea is that the first `09` and the `09` in `09x` must match?

Comment: (1) What do you think `$1` inside a regexp would mean? (Hint: it would mean the end of the string, followed by a `1`.) (2) Why are you testing with `RegExp.test` before replacing? (Hint: you don't need to, since the replacement would not happen anyway unless there was a match.) (3) Why are you escaping the underscore? (Hint: you don't need to.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```js
var input = "/09/small_image/09x/";
var output = input.replace(/(\/\d+\/)small_image\/\d*x/, "$1thumbnail");
console.log(output);
```

Explanation:

Put the part you want to *keep* in parentheses, then refer to that as `$1` in the *replacement string* - don't put `$1` in your regex. So `(\/\d+\/)` means to match a forward slash followed by one or more digits, followed by another forward slash.

(Note that you don't need to escape underscores in a regex.)

Comment: more strictly: `/\/(\d+)\/small_image\/\1x/`

Comment: thank you for explanation!!  does $1  means cound be group another part as $2 $3 ...

Comment: @Tibrogargan - I considered using `\1`, but note that the way you've shown wouldn't quite work because of the leading `\/` inside the sub match.

Comment: @user1775888 - Yes. And the `\1` thing that Tibrogargan and I were talking about in the regex means to match the previous submatch, so for your purposes to make sure you have `09...09x` and not `09...08x`.

Comment: @nnnnnn what it there exist another `( ... )` part but don't want it become $x is it possible to escape it

Comment: If you mean you want to match a `(` in the input you have to escape it in the regex as `\(`. If you mean you want to group something in the regex but not have it become a numbered submatch you can use a non-capturing group with `(?:something)` as explained at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). (Note also that just because something became a numbered sub match doesn't mean you have to actually use it in your replacement. You could do a replacement of `"$1xyz$5"`, ignoring submatches 2-4.)

Comment: That's a non capturing group.   Use `(?:term)`.  Problem is, because you didn't capture it you can't use it with `\n`

Comment: yes I want make it not become a numbered submatch.  thanks so much!!! I get it now

Answer (score 2):

Go with

```
var regexPattern = /(\/\d+\/)small\_image\/\d*x/;
```

and

```
str = str.replace(regexPattern, '$1thumbnail');
```

**First**, you were missing the `+`. Because `09` are two digits, you need the regexp to match one or more digits (`\ḑ` would be exactly one). This is accomplished by `\d+`
**Second**, everything you match is being removed at first. To get the `/09/` part back afterwards, you have to remember it by putting it into brackets in the regexp `(`...`)` and afterwards reference it in the replacement via `$1`
One could as well create other groups and reference them by `$2`,`$3` ...