# Changing Parantheses to Square Brackets With Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Under Visual Studio 2019 I am trying to replace Parantheses with Square Brackets

For example: `fld(126)` to `fld[126]`

Using this regular expression

```
fld[\(][0-9]*[\)]
```

matches good what I look for in the code.

But \2 replaces everything between parentheses with '\2' instead of leaving what exists there before.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing only a part of regexp matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995322/replacing-only-a-part-of-regexp-matching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example RegEx shows you only want to change the brackets for the function `fld`.

Use

```
Find:  fld\((\d*)\)
Replace:  fld[$1]
```

If the content between the brackets can be more than numbers use

```
Find:  fld\(([^)]*)\)
Replace:  fld[$1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ([^(\s]+)\(([^)]+)\)(?!\S)
Replace: $1[$2]
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
([^(\s]+)   match AND capture the leading 'fld' term, in $1
            this is given by all non '(' and whitespace characters
\(          match a literal (
([^)]+)     match AND capture the content inside parentheses, in $2
\)          match a literal )
(?!\S)      assert that what follows the closing ) is a boundary or whitespace
```

Comment: finds, but still inserts $2 (or whatever you write) , instead of old content between parantheses (maybe this case requires an adjustment to VS)

Comment: @BIRYAZILIM Try using this as the replacement: `\1[\2]` or maybe `\\1[\\2]` ... not all regex engines use exactly the same syntax.